# Is there a way to see another user's opened files and diffs in Perforce (command-line)?

Tags: diff, perforce

A coworker has gone away for the holidays and I'm trying to figure out what he's already implemented or hasn't so we don't duplicate our efforts. Is there a way to see `p4 diff` as if from his view? Or maybe some trick to setting up a new `p4 client` so that I can achieve this?

Worst case, I can run some kind of recursive diff between his root and a "clean" client, but as always, looking for a more direct approach.

Comment: has he shelved the files? if so you can diff that.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files aren't shelved, the changed versions only exist on his machine, so you will need access to his machine to see the diffs; the Perforce server does not have a copy of them.

If you have access to his machine and his client isn't locked, just use his client and run "p4 diff" (you don't need to be logged in to Perforce as the same user, provided you have physical access to his client machine and your Perforce user has permission to view the depot file).

If his client is locked, you can create a new client on his machine that maps the same files, but the potential for confusion is high there so I'd recommend instead just grabbing the files off his machine and copying them to your own workspace (use "p4 reconcile" to automatically detect and open the ones that are different).